# Discrete ContourPlot3D with restrictions

Tags: plotting, rule

I have the follow simple condition between integers: `k - 2 h - l == 0`, which describe a plane that I plot with:

```
ContourPlot3D[x - 2*y - z == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Now the problem I have is: How can I plot the same plane under these restrictions:

- plot only discrete numbers (x = 1, 2, 3, ...; y = 1, 2, 3, ...; z = 1, 2, 3, ...);
- *Mathematica* should observe rules on the integers (e.g.: plot only the positive integers for which `k ≠ h`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to separately see the plane, the grid of integer point positions, and those points that meet your criteria, you might want to try something like this:

```
With[{max=2,plane={x,y,z}\[Function]x-2y-z==0},
  Module[{zz,grid,filter},
    zz=z/.Solve[plane[x,y,z],z];
    grid=Select[Tuples[Range[-max,max],3],p\[Function]plane@@p];
    filter[{k_,h_,l_}]:=(k>=0)&&(h>=0)&&(l>=0)&&(k!=h);
    Show[{
      ParametricPlot3D[{x,y,zz},{x,-max,max},{y,-max,max},Mesh->None,PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[0.5],Gray]],
      Graphics3D[{
        {Gray,Opacity[0.5],Sphere[#,0.19]&/@grid},
        {Red,Sphere[#,0.2]&/@Select[grid,filter]}
      }]
    },BoxRatios->{1,1,1},PlotRange->max+0.5,Lighting->"Neutral"]
  ]
]
```

[image]

You might want to set max to a larger value to see how the set of selected points looks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the sort of thing you mean?

```
rgnFn[{x_, y_, z_}] := x - 2*y - z == 0;
Graphics3D[
 Translate[Cuboid[], Select[Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 3], rgnFn] - 1/2], 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Select` here is used to pick the coordinates to be plotted.  Subtracting `1/2` above centers the cube on the coordinate.

```
Select[Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 3], rgnFn]
(*
  {{-2, -2,  2}, {-2, -1,  0}, {-2,  0, -2}, {-1, -1,  1}, {-1,  0, -1},
   { 0, -1,  2}, { 0,  0,  0}, { 0,  1, -2}, { 1,  0,  1}, { 1,  1, -1},
   { 2,  0,  2}, { 2,  1,  0}, { 2,  2, -2}}
*)
```

Comment: @micheal thanks a lot, this can fit the answer of the first question pretty good. Thanks again.

Comment: @PanichiPattumerosPapaCastoro If you also want to constrain `x != y`, then change the region function to `rgnFn[{x_, y_, z_}] := x - 2*y - z == 0 && x != y`.

Comment: @PanichiPattumerosPapaCastoro Please, take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).